# Buttons disabled on edit template form crm 2011 + IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, dynamics-crm-2011, internet-explorer-10

What's wrong with Template edit form in IE10? All buttons are disabled (marked in picture below). Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Change the browser mode to IE 10 Compatibility View to resolve a lot of issues with CRM.  Some issues on the Form Editor I still haven't been able to resolve though, and had to VM into a machine with IE 9.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help in this case